# ruby DateTime#strptime cannot handle '%6N'?

Tags: ruby

```
time_format = '%H.%M.%S.%6N'
timestamp = DateTime.now.strftime(time_format)  # this works, it shows something like "10.09.53.595977"
DateTime.strptime(timestamp, time_format)  # error, in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

So is it possible to make the #strptime work if I really want to parse the microsecond (6 digits) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ruby source code at ext/date/date_strptime.c it seems the N case is taken into account, try this:

```
DateTime.strptime(timestamp, '%H.%M.%S.%N')
```

And to check the seconds fraction was parsed try this:

```
d = DateTime.strptime(timestamp, '%H.%M.%S.%N')
p d.sec_fraction
```

And compare it with what you have in *time_format*.

Comment: The `%N` part is parsed, but `%6N` is not a recognized token. It doesn't appear to work like `strftime` does.

Comment: It doesn't. I've created an issue about it and revision [35312](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/35312) adds a line in the docs for this.

Comment: Thank you Luis for created an issue about it.